# How to draw astroid given by Parametric equation $a(t)=(\cos^3(t),\sin^3(t) )$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, curves

I wanted to draw Asteroid with parametric equation  $a(t)=(\cos^3(t),\sin^3(t) )$

I know that $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$ is equation . Also $x^2+y^2=1$ is equation of circle.  By using online app I had drawn that . But I do not know what is process of drawing by hand .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Construct unit radii from various points on the $x$ axis between $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ to the $y$ axis, maybe?  The astroid is the envelope of these radii.

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by *drawing by hand*? Is it finding symmetries, inflection points...?

Comment: The same way to draw any graph by hand (or by computer): select a bunch of values for $t$ - because of the trig functions, values between $0$ and $2\pi$ are sufficient - then calculate and plot the corresponding points, and then connect the dots.

Comment: Use the so-called "sliding ladder problem" to get a quarter of astroid as an envelope (http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/ladder.htm#Sliding%20Ladder%20Problems).